# Save an excel file from a dataframe pandas to sharepoint (office365 API)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sharepoint, office365api

I have this dataframe, and I want to save it as a excel file in a sharepoint folder.

This is my code:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

# auth
client_credentials = ClientCredential(var_client_id, var_client_secret)
ctx = ClientContext(var_sp_site).with_credentials(client_credentials)

df = pd.DataFrame(sql_table)

var_relative_url = "sharepoint_path/sharepoint_path"

target_folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(var_relative_url)

target_folder.upload_file(content=df.to_excel(excel_writer='teste.xlsx'), file_name='teste.xlsx').execute_query() # Here is my problem
```

When I execute this code, the excel file is created at the folder, but when I try to open the file on sharepoint interface it raises a error ("cannot be opened").

This code will run on a cloud function, so I can't use local files to upload.

Answer (score 0):

I'm investigating this issue right now. Not solved yet buy I can give you a work around: use .save()

```
wb = pd.ExcelWriter( outputFile, mode='w', engine="openpyxl" )
myDataFrame.to_excel( wb, sheet_name='sheet1', index=False )
wb.save()
```

From error to warning ;)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: outputFile should be an path to export file,right? how to handle if the path should be a sharepoint path?